# powershell script takes hours to execute

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to update SharePoint list with a PowerShell script. This list contains around 50,000 items. Getting the required list item takes more than an hour, then to perform update takes even longer.

Below are the lines of code taking so long to execute:

```
$url = "http://abcd/"

$listNameRequestProgress = "RequestProgress"

$web = get-SPWeb $url

$listNameRequestProgressObj = $web.lists[$listNameRequestProgress]

$itemRequestProgress = $listNameRequestProgressObj.Items | ? {$_.ID -eq 47809} #takes long time

$itemRequestProgress["Assigned"] = "616;#abcd"   
$itemRequestProgress.UpdateOverwriteVersion()  #takes long time
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't comment due to reputation < 50. So, commenting in this section.

Please post the code clearly. What is $listNameRequestProgressObj ? How it's getting created ?
What is the output of $listNameRequestProgressObj | gm  command? You may find some useful method there.

From high-level look into this, U can say that in

```
$itemRequestProgress = $listNameRequestProgressObj.Items | ? {$_.ID -eq 47809}
```

You are getting all the items and then using WHERE clause.
If possible, use something like -Filter so that you don't have to process all the "Items" in the list.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. I have revised the post and added the remaining code.   Thanks

Comment: See the documentation of Get-SPWeb.http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607807(v=office.15).aspx There is a "-Filter" parameter available. Basically, you need to change $web.lists[$listNameRequestProgress] with Get-SPWeb -Filter "$_.SomeProperty=$listNameRequestProgress "